# apex:selectList value is always returing null to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

im trying get the selected recordtype into the controller to build additional rendering logic in showTranLog() method based on input selection but its always returning null. when i insert the record in saveproceed() method its getting set fine.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="TaskExtensionCtrl">

  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="New Log" mode="edit" id='pb'>
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="selectedRecordType" columns="1">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Choose Record Type" for="rt" />         
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedrecType}" multiselect="false"  size="1" required="true">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!rectypes}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!showTranLog}" reRender="pb" status="status" immediate="true"/>
            </apex:selectList> 
            </apex:panelGrid>       
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
     <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveAndProceed}" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class TaskExtensionCtrl {
    public String partId;
    public Task task {get;set;}
    public boolean isShowTranLog  {get;set;}{isShowTranLog=false;}
    public string selectedrecType{get;set;}

    public TaskExtensionCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        partId=ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().get('id');
        createTaskRecord();
    }

    public void createTaskRecord() {
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.error,'in creat task'+selectedrecType);
        task = new Task();
    }
    public PageReference showTranLog(){
          this.isShowTranLog = true;
          system.debug(LoggingLevel.error,'task record type in showTranLog#'+ task.RecordTypeID+Task);
          return null;
     }    
    public List<SelectOption> getrectypes() {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('','--Select Record Type --'));
        for(RecordType rt:[select id,name from RecordType where sobjecttype='task']){
            options.add(new SelectOption(rt.id,rt.name));    
        }
        return options;
    }

    public String getselectedrecType() {
        return selectedrecType;
    }

    public void setselectedrecType(String selectedrecType) {
        this.selectedrecType= selectedrecType;
    }

    public PageReference saveAndProceed() {

        try {
            task.RecordTypeID=selectedrecType;
        insert task;
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.error,'In Save#'+ task+task.RecordTypeID+task.RecordType);
        } 
        catch(DMLException e) {
        task.addError(e.getMessage());
        return null;
        }

        PageReference pf = new PageReference('/' + task.Id + '?retURL=/' + partId);
        pf.setRedirect(true);
        return pf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have the selected recordtype getter and setter at the top of your class:

```
public string selectedrecType{get;set;}
```

just remove this additional getter and setter:

```
public String getselectedrecType() {
    return selectedrecType;
}

public void setselectedrecType(String selectedrecType) {
    this.selectedrecType= selectedrecType;
}
```

and remove the `immediate="true"` (or set it to `false`) from `ActionSupport`

setting `immediate` to true when calling controller action will execute the action in the backend, but it won't carry the form data with it. so you need to set it to `false`

Comment: i commented the getter/setter and its still returning null.

Comment: you also need to set `immediate` to `false` (or remove it). edited my answer

Comment: i have already set immediate to true and tried removing ..still the same. no luck.

Comment: i meant set to false, as mentioned in the Answer.

Comment: Sorry no luck..still same

Comment: let me take a step back. it worked if i set it to false. Thanks You.